# didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation does not fire entering PortraitUpsideDown on iPad Simulator

Tags: ipad, simulator

Our application starts in landscape mode ... in the plist Initial Interface Orientation is set to "Landscape (left home button)".

When debugging with the iPad simulator, after the application starts, we rotate the simulated iPad using either the menu option Hardware > Rotate Left or using the keyboard command-LeftArrow.

By placing a breakpoint in the View Controller at the entry point for didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation; we observe the breakpoint being hit when rotating into all positions except portrait-upside-down.

This happens if we rotate to the right as well.  The breakpoint is hit when rotating into all positions except portrait-upside down.

Is this a known issue, or is there something required to activate this capability?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the post, duh.

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation does not explicitly assert UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown.

So yes, there is something required to activate this capability.

Hope this helps others in the future.